# Create a sort of Cartesian product of dataframe columns, based on the present combinations in the data

Tags: python, combinations, cartesian-product

Currently I am working with product data (coming from a webshop), and these products have an hierarchical category structure (category 1, 2, 3) with 3 being the 'most specific category' (think of : Football shoes (1), Artificial Grass shoes (2), Adidas (3)).

As the dataset contains over 25000 entries, I began looking for a way to create a sort of mapping that can tell me the following: 
What possible combinations of 1,2,3 (or just 1,2) are present in the data? By this I do not mean **all possible combinations**, but simply those that are present in the data.

I quickly came to the **Cartesian product**, using `itertools`. However, next to me running into a `memory error`, I believe `itertools` (and the idea of the Cartesian product) is to make all possible combinations of 1,2,3 (and not just those that are actually present).

Consider the following dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product ID': [1,2,3,4], 'Category 1': ['A','B','B','B'], 'Category 2':['C', 'D', 'D', 'E']})
```

So in this case, I would like to see the following output: 
`A, C`, `B,D`, `B,E`.

I hope it is clear :)

**PS**: Could someone explain how I can add 'Dataframe blocks' to a StackOverflow question, instead of a dictionary such as this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(df['Category 1'] + df['Category 2']).unique()`

Or if you want to count the combinations:

`(df['Category 1'] + df['Category 2']).value_counts()`

Comment: Oh damn, that was too easy actually.. Much appreciated!